# DotNetZip freezing my application?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetnuke

```
            string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);    
            public void unzip(String zFile)
            {
                Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(zFile);
                zip.ExtractProgress += new EventHandler<ExtractProgressEventArgs>(zip_ExtractProgress);
                zip.ExtractAll(desktop + "\\cache", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
                zip.Dispose();
                zip = null;
            }

            void zip_ExtractProgress(object sender, ExtractProgressEventArgs e)
            {

                if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Extracting_EntryBytesWritten)
                {
                    label2.Text = "debug: " + ((e.EntriesExtracted));
                }
                else if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Extracting_BeforeExtractEntry)
                {
                    label3.Text = e.CurrentEntry.FileName;
                }
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                unzip(desktop + "\\cache.zip");
            }
```

When I execute the unzip button1_Click() my application freezes.  I'm new to C# and I'm not really sure how to fix this, can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long running blocking operations should not run on the main UI thread, since as you can see the UI will freeze up.

Consider using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to do the work on a separate thread.

There's a good summary [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx).

Report progress back to the UI by handling the ProgressChanged event and calling backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(), rather than directly updating label2.Text from inside there.

i.e. from inside your zip_ExtractProgress method, call backgroundWorker.ReportProgress

Comment: I tried using the background worker but it kept saying my threads were not safe.  How do I counter that? I read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=VS.100).aspx but it wasn't working out for me.  I must have been doing it wrong.

Comment: You were probably updating the UI directly from inside your DoWork event hander method. Instead update your UI from inside a method wired up to the ProgressChanged, and report progress using backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(). You can pass any object you need out from your worker method to ProgressChanged.

Answer (score 2):

```
 label3.Text = e.CurrentEntry.FileName;
 label3.Update();
```

The Update() method ensures that the label is painted, now showing the Text property you assigned.  Without it, the painting doesn't happen until the unzipping code stops running and your program goes idle again.  Otherwise known as 'pumping the message loop'.  Calling Update() is only a partial fix, your window is still catatonic and won't respond to mouse clicks for example.  If it takes longer than a couple of seconds, Windows displays the "Not responding" ghost window.

Get some experience with coding in C#, then tackle threading with the BackgroundWorker class.

Comment: I really don't think this is good advice - it's very much not the right way to do this.

Comment: It solves the OP's problem, doing so with keeping in mind that he just got started in C#.  Getting BGW right is not a beginner task, it has far too many pitfalls.  "Get some experience" is good advice, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way: Execute the unzip method using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx). Be sure to modify GUI controls only on the main GUI thread, by using Invoke.